# GWT: gray areas in Google Maps v3

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3, jsni

[Google Maps API V3 Gray Areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214651/google-maps-api-v3-gray-areas)

Here, it says we need to call google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') to prevent gray areas on map.

Is there any other way in GWT? If not, how can I call it on GWT without JSNI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry. map.triggerResize(); is the answer.